# How do I get LinqToSql to pass “index hints” to sql server?

Tags: .net, sql-server, linq-to-sql

As we can’t trust our customers to update the index stats etc in sql server, we have in the past had to use [index hints](http://www.sql-server-performance.com/tips/hints_general_p1.aspx).   (As some of our customers are still on Sql Server 2000, we also can’t depend on the better query optimizer in later version of Sql Server).

So how do I pass in index hints when using LinqToSql to build a query rather than raw Sql?

Comment: Why do they need to keep the statistics updated? You should have them on auto update - and can easily run an update script every weekend. In 20 years I never had problems with statistics updates.

Comment: I have to agree with @TomTom on this one... this isn't really the kind of problem that index hints were intended to solve, and I think you'd get a lot better mileage out of forcing a statistics update either via auto-update (which is enabled by default) or by having your own background process that runs `UPDATE STATISTICS` or `sp_updatestats` if you're worried that they'll turn off auto-update.

Comment: @Tom, the systems need to run 24*7, so "update scripts" etc are very hard to get agreement to, and I don't know if the people that install the systems even understand what they are.  The problem with out of data statistics may just be a "old wifes tale" but it is what I have been told when I have asked why "index hints" are used.  I may get away without using any index hints, but I am tring to cover my bases hare.

Comment: Why? SQL Server Enterprise (the ONLY one usable ina 24/7 scenario seriously, as it has all the nice high availability features) support regerenerating an index WITHOUT INTERRUPTION ;)

Comment: @TomTom funny! not everyone has $15,000 laying around - especially not people using Linq2Sql ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not something that is supported, you only options over a query is to set the transaction isolation level, but that doesn't help with this issue.

I would recommend one of two courses of action is this is something that you really need to do.

1. You can write a stored procedure and handle this within your procedure and use LINQ to call it....
2. Move away from LINQ to SQL

Personally, IF this is really necessary I would recommend option two.  If in fact you must take that level of action/control over your database calls, auto-generated SQL is going to be problematic for you at later points as well.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this is not possible. The only thing you can do is influence the transaction isolation level. See an example of this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2220769/how-to-use-withnolock-in-linq-to-sql/2220937#2220937).