# How to SET FORCEPLAN ON using EntityFramework?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

In order to perform a specific query, i need to set `Forceplan` on for the current SQL connection, otherwise it will run indeterminately.

I try this with no success:

```
dc = new MyDbContext();
dc.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("SET FORCEPLAN ON"); 
dc.sometable.where ...query
```

Comment: read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8031069/how-can-i-specify-an-index-hint-in-entity-framework you should be able to make a plan

Comment: In the interests of sheer curiosity, what is your use case for `FORCEPLAN`? I'm not saying you shouldn't use it, I'm just curious to see where people use it and why

Comment: The cause should be related with the use of a linked server in a query. The problem popped out when we move the database on one side to other server.