# adding Index hint in Entity Framework Dotnet core

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core

Does Dotnet core EF natively provides support for Index Hint in the SELECT query?  If not how to improve query performance

Comment: Which query? Does hint improves your query? And no, hints are not supported.

Comment: SELECT queries. Editing the main question as well!

Comment: Show your particular  LINQ query. Claiming that something is slow - it is not right way to get correct result.

Comment: You can you [Interceptors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/logging-events-diagnostics/interceptors#example-command-interception-to-add-query-hints) to add query hints. But it's better to try to do without them.

Comment: Forget about EF. Take a look at the magnificent linq2db. It has the ability to use hints: [Query Extensions](https://linq2db.github.io/articles/sql/Query-Extensions.html)

Answer (score 0):

The current version of EF Core does not support index hints because integrating provider-specific hints into queries is complicated by the support for a particular provider's SQL dialect.

There is a discussion about [index hints in EF Core](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/6717) on Github, probably they will have this feature in the future.

You can use the [DbCommandInterceptor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8031069/how-can-i-specify-an-index-hint-in-entity-framework/67743682#67743682) approach to deal with it for now.